# Create a from with a date input in format without special characters + validation

Tags: jquery, html, validation, date, input

I want to create a form which will require the user to enter a date in this format: "ddmmyyyy". No slashed, no dots, no other special characters. And I want only the use of this format to be valid, otherwise I want to generate an error message.
So - for example, valid answers will be:

08101974
22032019
01011987

and invalid answers will be:

40779999
88229933
10152000

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions and the javascript `.match()` function

```js
$("#theForm").on("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var theDate = $("input[name='date']").val().trim();
  var dateMatch = theDate.match(/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0?[1-9]|1[012])\d{4}$/im);
  if (dateMatch)
    alert("Correct!!!")
  else
    alert("Invalid date dude!!!")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="theForm">
  <label>Date: </label>
  <input type="text" name="date"/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

1. `^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` matches any day in `0n` or `n` format from the beginning
2. `(0?[1-9]|1[012])` matches any month in `0n` or `n` from `0-12` format from the beginning
3. `\d{4}` matches any four digit number for a year right before the end of the string

Comment: wait - I tried it and now I see a date like 08101974 give an invalid alert too...

Comment: make sure there's no spaces, I've adjusted the code to trim whitespaces

Comment: I am curious if it would be wise to use Regex to any solution, from I got to understand it is better to stay away from those if you do not know the ins and outs of such as they may contain irreversible bugs and are hard to either locate or solve. There are some alternatives, what kind of project are you running? (E.g. when you are using asp.net mvc you could stick with data annotations which do the job for you)

Comment: The snippet works here, but for some reason not here: [link](http://outofsite.co.il/magic/2019/04/26/test/)

Comment: I'm so sorry there's a syntax error in `var theDate = $("input[name]").val().trim()`, it's supposed to be `var theDate = $("input[name='date']").val().trim()`. I've amended the change.

Comment: Perfect!! Thx very much